# Sort articles by most commented using disqus

Tags: comments, blogs, modx, disqus

I'm using disqus for my MODx blog commenting system, but couldn't find anywhere a way to sort my articles based on the most commented one, or the most recent comments.

I see that there are already many questions similar to this so any help will be much appreciated us.

Answer (score 0):

[An article](http://setpro.net.pl/software/ditto-stuff/most-commented) describing how to do it using Ditto/jot, it shouldn't be too difficult to modify it to work with disqus.

Comment: so how do you exactly do that? i've seen that ditto uses another sql database, but can we put the comments into our own database in disqus? thanks in advance for the time :D

Comment: haven't actually got this around, anyone has a solution??

Comment: You'll need to communicate with Disqus through their API and match that up with your resources. I'm thinking this one: http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/details/